# Observable in angular failed to subscribe on constructor or ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a observable concept in my application where i have my service which gets called by component1 and emit an event which subscribed by the component 2.

Please find my code below

Sercive Code

```
export class MessageService {
    private subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>("");
    message$ = this.subject.asObservable();
    //observ : Observable <String>;
    sendMessage(message: string) { 
        console.log('sendMesg',message)
        this.subject.next({ text: message });

    }
    clearMessage() {
        this.subject.next("");
   }
```

Component1 Code

```
  this.data.sendMessage('Printed');
```

Component2 Code

```
providers: [JsonDataService, MessageService]

constructor(public data?: MessageService)
{}
ngOnInit() {

    this.data.message$.subscribe(res => { console.log('res', res); }, err => { console.log('errrorr', err) });
}
```

i am getting console when message is passed to the sendMessage function but i am unable to get the console as well as any response from the subscribe method mentioned in the component2

Comment: `providers: [JsonDataService, MessageService]` breaks the  singleton pattern Register your service in parent component or root module

Comment: Have a look https://angular.io/guide/providers

Comment: I implemented the same and moved the service into app.module.ts but still i am getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the official document the common instance of the service should get shared by the Components.
I have declared the service in both the components hence unable to get the data emitted by service.

By moveing the service declaration in providers array of the app.module this got resolved.

Thanks @Vikas For giving hint.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure to call both component. I have tried and it is working.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-djgzb6

Comment: Yes it worked by removing the provider array from both the components and adding it to app.module.